# What's the right test case to find which method call is faster between execute and getElementsByTagName?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

What's the right test case to find which method call is faster between `XPathExpression.execute("child::")` and `Element.getElementsByTagName("")`?

Via DOM search:

```
NodeList nl = ((Element)this.currentNode).getElementsByTagName("*");
```

or via XPath:

```
public static final <T> T xpath(QName qType, Node n, String exp) {
    try {
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(exp);
        T result = (T) expr.evaluate(n, qType);
        return result;
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

**P.S.**

I put the code also to ask what improvement I could choose to enhance XPath compilation,
eg: moving `XPathExpression expr` outside the method context and caching exp instances with similar xpath expressions?

Answer (score 0):

The right test case is to build two versions of your application, one of which uses each alternative but which are otherwise identical, and **profile them** in the typical situations you're trying to improve performance in.

Any other test would be potentially misleading as it's not measuring *what you actually care about*, which is application performance.

Alternatively, if you're not looking at this from the point of view of top-down application performance, then you should stop optimising prematurely and simply write the most understandable code right now (and optimise if/when you can *measure* that this block of code is making your app/library unacceptably sluggish).